# How to make awk grab string in between a second set of single-quotes

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Please help, this is driving me mad.

I've got a standard Wp-config.php file and I'm trying to get awk to output only the database name, database username and password on a single line, but no matter what I try it spits out either irrelevant nonsense or syntax errors.

```
define('DB_NAME', 'pinkywp_wrdp1');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'pinkywp_user1');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'Mq2uMCLuGvfyw');
```

Desired output:

```
pinkywp_wrdp1 pinkywp_user1 Mq2uMCLuGvfyw
```

Actual output:

```
./dbinfo.sh: line 28: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
./dbinfo.sh: line 73: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Where is your code? How are we supposed to tell what you're doing wrong?

Comment: The error message suggests that you have mismatched quotes in your script. shellcheck.net should help.

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F"'" '$1~/^define/ && $2~/^DB_/{ printf "%s%s", $4, (++cnt%3 ? OFS : ORS)}'
pinkywp_wrdp1 pinkywp_user1 Mq2uMCLuGvfyw
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ed, this worked great. How would I need to modify this line in order to grab the text from in between the first or just one set of single quotes? For example in order to get `pinkygem_jmuser` from a line that reads `public $user = 'pinkygem_jmuser';`.

Comment: You're welcome. Think about it for a few seconds then try what you came up with and ask a followup question if you cant figure it out. It's extremely obvious so I expect you'll get it right away.

Comment: Hi Ed. I actually ended up doing it with `egrep 'user|password|db\s' file  | awk -F"'" {'print $(NF-1)'}` but thank you so-so much for your help! Have a wonderful (Valentine's) day.

Comment: You never need grep when you're using awk. It's just the same command but with new values plugged in: `awk -F"'" '$1~/^public/ && $2~/^\$user/{ printf "%s%s", $2, (++cnt%3 ? OFS : ORS)}'`

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk:

Use `'` as field separator and if current line contains 5 columns, print content of column 4 with a trailing blank.

```
awk -F "'" 'NF==5 {printf("%s ",$4)}' file
```

Output:

```
pinkywp_wrdp1 pinkywp_user1 Mq2uMCLuGvfyw
```

Comment: Thanks, this works!  How would I need to modify this line in order to grab the text from in between the first or just one set of single quotes? For example in order to get pinkygem_jmuser from a line that reads public $user = 'pinkygem_jmuser';

Comment: `echo "public $user = 'pinkygem_jmuser';" | awk -F "'" '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 1):

A few **`awk`** solutions:

1) with GNU *flavor*:

```
awk -v RS="');" '{ printf "%s%s", (NR==1? "":OFS), substr($NF, 2) }END{ print "" }' file
```

---

2) quotes-independant solution:

```
awk -F', ' '/define/{ 
                gsub(/^["\047]|["\047]\);$/, "", $2);
                printf "%s%s", (NR==1? "":" "), $2
            }
            END{ print "" }' file
```

The output (for both approaches):

```
pinkywp_wrdp1 pinkywp_user1 Mq2uMCLuGvfyw
```